# ProxySQL - Different MySQL servers

Tags: mysql, proxysql

### I wanted to use ProxySQL to manage two groups of servers that would have different databases, how could this be done?

**Example:**

**X instance group**

Write server 1

Read Server 2 - Replicate

Read Server 3 - Replicate

- database a
- database b
- database c

---

**Y instance group**

Write server 3

Read Server 4 - Replicate

Read Server 5 - Replicate

- database d
- database e

Answer (score 0):

set two services

/usr/lib/systemd/system/proxysql1.service  for X instance group

/usr/lib/systemd/system/proxysql2.service  for X instance group

Answer (score 0):

Each Group would have two hostgroups

example: (first host group in every server is write,   second hostgroup is read)
cluster 1
HG 1 server  1  weight 1
HG 2 server  1  weight 2
HG 1 server  2  weight 2
HG 2 server  2  weight 1
cluster 2
HG 3 server  3  weight 1
HG 4 server  3  weight 2
HG 3 server  4  weight 2
HG 4 server  4  weight 1

then make a rule to direct traffic to the correct cluster based on scheme

i would also make a user that is default for every cluster aswell